# Android parsing json array

Tags: android, json

How i can parse this type of json array?

```
{
    "Success": "Yes",
    "FuelPrice": {
        "Coastal": {
            "Petrol": "R12.53",
            "Diesel": "R13.10"
        },
        "Inland": {
            "Petrol": "R12.85",
            "Diesel": "R 13.85"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no json array

Comment: sorry my mistake imean object.

Comment: How is the json stored?

Comment: use this ....http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: These all are JSON Objects . You can use follwoing mentof to solve it


    JSONObject object=new JSONObject(myString);
    JSONObject object1=object.getJSONObject("FuelPrice");
    JSONObject object2=object1.getJSONObject("Coastal");
    String s1=object2.getString("Petrol");
    String s2=object2.getString("Diesel");

You can access all data in same way

Comment: @Raghunandan ok i will upload my code and also i have briefly defined that what i want..

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal thanks alot ur code works :)

Answer (score 2):

Use following function to parse your JSONObject.

```
public static JSONObject getJSONObjectfromURL(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jObject = null;

        // http post
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            // Log.e("result:",""+result);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jObject = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jObject;
    }
```